# python script for selecting and deleting files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I accidently made copies of a lot of files on my computer.
But one thing I noticed was that they all ended with the suffix ".copy", so in order to delete them I would like to write a python script to select these files and then deleting them.
How do i go about doing that?

Comment: use `find`, it would be easier: `find . -iname "*.copy" -delete`

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

dir = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Directory' # if using Windows
#dir = '/path/to/directory'  # if using Linux/OS X

files = [os.path.join(dir, f) for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(dir) for f in files if f.endswith('.copy')]

for f in files:
    print f
    # os.remove.path(f)
```

This will iterate through all files and folders starting at the root `dir`

Remove the hash tag `#` in front of `os.remove.path` after the first run once you've verified the correct files are being removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
for file_name in os.listdir("path/to/the/folder_with_files"):
    if file_name.endswith('.copy'):
        os. delete(file_name)
```

Hopes that work.